# How to add metric-server inside an helm-couchdb application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hpa

When trying to do HorizontalPodAutoscaling I'm getting (failed to get memory utilization: unable to get metrics for resource memory: no metrics returned from resource metrics API) how can solve this problem.[image]

Comment: What is your infrastructure? If it's on prem Did you install metrics-server as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#before-you-begin)? Metrics Server is a cluster-wide aggregator of resource usage data. Resource metrics are used by components like kubectl top and the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler to scale workloads.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand before using hpa you have to install metrics-server. More in below docs and links.

### [Before you begin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)

> This example requires a running Kubernetes cluster and kubectl, version 1.2 or later. [**metrics-server**](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) **monitoring needs to be deployed in the cluster** to provide metrics via the resource metrics API, as Horizontal Pod Autoscaler uses this API to collect metrics. **The instructions for deploying this are on the GitHub repository of [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server)**, if you followed getting started on GCE guide, metrics-server monitoring will be turned-on by default.

### [Kubernetes metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#kubernetes-metrics-server)

> Metrics Server collects resource metrics from Kubelets and exposes them in Kubernetes apiserver through Metrics API for use by Horizontal Pod Autoscaler and Vertical Pod Autoscaler.

Additional links:

- https://www.cloudtechnologyexperts.com/autoscaling-microservices-in-kubernetes-with-horizontal-pod-autoscaler/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dALta9zQkfs